# Electric Flux vs Magnetic Flux Units

Tags: gauss-law

If electric flux is the number of electric field lines through a surface area and magnetic flux is a number of magnetic field lines through a surface area, why are the units for them different?

Electric Flux:

[image]

Magnetic Flux:

[image]

Mathematically, I know that the units of E field are different from B Field so it makes sense that the units for the fluxes are different. I see E field and M field, however, as two sides of the same coin so I would think they carry the same units. Really just looking for other's thoughts on this matter.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Magnetic flux is measured in $Wb$ but magnetic flux density (which is what's written in the image you posted) is measured in $Wb/m^2$ which is Tesla.

To put in better/clear forms, electric flux and magnetic flux units can be written as

$$Wb = \frac{kg \cdot m^2}{s^2 \cdot A} = V\cdot s = T\cdot m^2 \hspace{3mm} (for\hspace{1mm} magnetic\hspace{1mm} flux) $$

$$\frac{kg \cdot m^3}{s^3 \cdot A} = V\cdot m \hspace{3mm} (for\hspace{1mm} electric\hspace{1mm} flux)$$